# Ember.js controller needs another controller - how do I listen for updates?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have the following controller:

```
Filters.FiltersProductsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: "filters",
    filters: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.filters"),
    content: function(){
        return this.store.findQuery('product', this.get('filters').getFilterParams());
    }.property()
});
```

On the initial page load it passes along the result of `getFilterParams` as I want.

I have two questions:

1. How do I listen for updates and make sure that the `findQuery` call is run again whenever the model data in the `FiltersController` is changed?
2. Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way would be to have the `content` property depend on the `model` property of the controller.

```
content: function() {
    return ...
}.property('controllers.filters.model')
```

If the `filters` controller is an array controller, you might want to watch `content.@each` instead of `model`.

Comment: Perfect. Watching `content.@each` worked since it is an `ArrayController`. I have an action that clears all records - this triggers the function to be called multiple times (between each record deletion). Is there a way to debounce the function or similar to make it not call the backend until all the calls are complete?

Comment: I don't think Ember has a built in way to do it. You'll have to write your own debouncing function for that.